# How to enable notifications on Calendar macOS for recurrent events?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, calendar, google-calendar

I created a few recurrent events from the Calendar app but none of them are being show as notifications, neither as popup notifications (those that appear on the top-right corner of the screen) nor on the sidebar to the right (the one that appears when I click the button to the right on the menu bar).

This is how one even looks on Calendar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you receive notifications for the other events (that are not repeated)?

Comment: @KevinGrabher yes, I do receive notification for holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure event notifications are enabled for whichever calendar you're adding the events to.

[image: Calendar Properties Dialog]

Comment: I don't have the option "Events affect availability" but I have the one that says "Ignore alerts" and it's unchecked, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

### The MACOS Calendar.app's workflow is a bit counterintuitive.

You would think that it would add at least a default type of notification (called "**alert**" in MACOS calendar.app )
for each event... it does not however. You have to pick and choose yourself.

---

Here is a quick example:

- I had added one default alert, and
- I am showing adding a Custom alert in progress:
  [image: Adding alerts (notifications) in MACOS Calendar.app]

The **Custom** alerts dropdown contains 4 options:

- Message
- Message with Sound
- Email
- Open File

These let you do more than just a popup with a beep.

---

So, to recap the whole process:

1. Open Callendar.app
2. Create Event (for example click the + in the Title bar to Create Quick Event)
3. In the right hand side customization bar, Click Add Alert below the Date of event.
4. Create the first alert by clicking at **None** next to **alert:** label and picking time or **Custom**
5. Add more alerts by clicking the **+** sign right of the last defined alert

Comment: I've been trying what you suggested, and notifications seems to work with iCloud calendars but not with Google calendars. That is notifications on macOS, but I'd like to have Google calendar notifications working too, since those will pop up on my Android device too. Any idea on how to accomplish that from the Calendar app on macOS?

Comment: @rraallvv - sorry, currently I have no access to android devices to test with, I may have tomorrow. Interesting problem.